# Can a company i no longer work for keep my my email address active

Tags: ethics, email, employees, employer

A company I used to work for a year and a half ago still has my email active.  I suppose to intercept any leads or info about me.  I'm not sure if they respond, but when I send emails to the old address it doesn't get kicked back to me nor does it have an auto response.  Is it legal for them to do this?  If so any ideas I can make them close it?

Comment: The fact that there is no "auto response" does not mean that your old e-mail address is "active". Companies can and should set up a "catch all" email address that intercepts incoming mail addressed to unknown persons/ex-employees. For example, a client has an old e-mail address in their address book and then sends it to "you" about some product, etc.

Comment: It's not your email, it's theirs. Unless they were misrepresenting that you still worked there then there's nothing you can do.

Comment: Why do you *care* whether the email address is still active? How does it affect you?

Comment: Just because an email isn't bounced, it doesn't mean that it's still being directed to an Inbox anywhere.  They might just be deleting all incoming mails unread.  But there's no way for you to know that.

Answer (score 4):

It's normal enough and legal anywhere I know (which isn't the whole World) to keep a former employees email active. I do it all the time, I just change the password, and usually set up an autoforward to another address so that any work related (which is all the employee should have been using it for anyway) emails are not lost.

If I remember I'll eventually delete or rename it after a month or so, if not, ~shrugs~

The email belongs to the company, not the former employee. Possibly you would have a case if the company is pretending you still work there and doing things with your name on it, but I've never heard of that happening.

Comment: Can the ex-employee list that email address with websites that send a lot of junk emails such as questionnaires and advertisements. This will make it a lot harder for the employer to find important emails and possibly delete the account.Is that legal?

Comment: If someone were to do something like that, it would probably be best not to ask or let anyone know. I have no idea if it's legal or not, I would advise against it as being a bit petty and quite possibly a waste of time depending on their spam filter.

Comment: @jerry215 I think the real lesson to learn here is to not use a work email address for things that you don't want the company to know. Which you clearly have and are now worried about. Contact the people that may be emailing you and give them an updated address.